# TypeError: path.resolve is not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I finished up an Ethereum smart contract course on Udemy that used solc@^0.4.17, React and Next.js. I thought it would be a fun exercise to try and upgrade everything to the latest version and try to refactor. I have the following code in a file called `factory.js` being imported into my main index file:

```
import web3 from './web3';
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const abiPath = path.resolve('ethereum/build', 'CampaignFactory.abi');
console.log(abiPath);

const abi = fs.readFileSync(abiPath, 'utf8');
console.log(abi);

const factory = new web3.eth.Contract(
    JSON.parse(abi),
    '0x2d54559dCe0DA6C92378A916e9eE0422CEFFCD80'
);

export default factory;
```

Inside of my main index file I'm calling it like so:

```
import factory from '../ethereum/factory';
...
class CampaignIndex extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps() {
        const campaigns = await factory.methods.getDeployedCampaigns().call();

        return { campaigns };
    }
...
```

Here's the console.log:

```
    wait  - compiling /...
    event - compiled successfully in 637 ms (1422 modules)
    /Users/sonnyparlin/Github/kickstart/ethereum/build/CampaignFactory.abi
    [
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "minimum",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "createCampaign",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "deployedCampaigns",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "",
            "type": "address"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getDeployedCampaigns",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "address[]",
            "name": "",
            "type": "address[]"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
      }
    ]
```

The console log confirms that `path.resolve()` is actually working, but when I go to the page via the web browser I see the following error:

[image]

```
Call Stack
Module../ethereum/factory.js
file:///Users/sonnyparlin/Github/kickstart/.next/static/chunks/pages/index.js (1148:1)
Module.options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (638:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/sonnyparlin/Github/kickstart/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (307:21)
eval
webpack-internal:///./pages/index.js (9:75)
Module../pages/index.js
file:///Users/sonnyparlin/Github/kickstart/.next/static/chunks/pages/index.js (1192:1)
Module.options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (638:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/sonnyparlin/Github/kickstart/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (307:21)
eval
node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-client-pages-loader.js?page=%2F&absolutePagePath=%2FUsers%2Fsonnyparlin%2FGithub%2Fkickstart%2Fpages%2Findex.js! (5:15)
eval
node_modules/next/dist/client/route-loader.js (236:50)
```

My guess is that this is really some kind of versioning or dependency issue, so I'm also including my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "kickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "dev": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.37",
    "fs-extra": "^10.0.0",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.1.8",
    "mocha": "^9.1.3",
    "next": "^12.0.3",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.4",
    "solc": "^0.8.9",
    "web3": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  }
}
```

And a listing of my project files:

[image]

Comment: Where exactly in your `index.js` file are you using `factory`? That will break if you use it in client-side code as it's using Node.js APIs (`path` & `fs`).

Comment: It's only being used in getInitialProps(), which I understand is legal.

Comment: Not quite. `getInitialProps` runs both on the server (first page load) and on the client (client-side page navigation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import factory.js, next is running entire file, it sees the "path" and it is throwing the error

`path` is used to get the directory of contract file, and `fs` is used to read the contract file. Then with `solc` compiler, you compile this code, you run this file with

```
  node fileName.js
```

based on instructions you defined with solc, this compilation with create a .json file which has "abi" property. So far we had nothing to do with next.js.

Then, refactor this to a separate file:

```
import abi from "directory/file.json"

const factory = new web3.eth.Contract(
    // pass the abi
    JSON.parse(abi),
    '0x2d54559dCe0DA6C92378A916e9eE0422CEFFCD80'
);
```

Now you have to import this into your next.js project.